# Odd Behaviour in Production Bot

Tags: c#, botframework, facebook-messenger

My bot has a welcome message it sends to new users.  We have this bot in three different environment, Dev, Staging and Production. All work as design apart from Production on the Facebook channel.

It seems Facebook is sending multiple messages at the start of the conversation. My welcome message has two versions, one with personalisation, which shows something like "Hi !" and one without "Hi!" for instances where there is no user information from the channel in use.

The strange thing is that Facebook is sending multiple messages:

The conversations looks like this:

Hi!
Hi!
Hi James!

With nothing send from the user to the bot inbetween these messages.

The bot is on our clients page and included on their web site via the Customer Chat Plugin which itself seems pretty buggy.

Has anyone else seen similar behaviour from the Facebook channel?

Comment: can you check if your bot is subscribed to events other than `pages_messaging` you're handling those events as well? also check if you have more than one bot registered to your page on developer.facebook.com.

Comment: I know there is only one bot registered to the page. And we are subscribed to messages, messaging_postbacks, messaging_optins, message_deliveries, messaging_referrals, standby, messaging_handovers

Comment: Are you handling those events as well? like message_deliveries, it might be that your bot is getting multiple message events and handling them as messages.

Comment: Could it be possible that some of the non "messages" deliveries to the bot still use the btoframework `ActivityTypes.Message` ... ? Also would the Live/In Development have an effect on this as out Dev and Staging bots subscribe to the same events but dont display this issue.

Comment: The only events it deals with are inside `if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message) { / code / }` Do any of those other events get delivered with the `messages` ActivityTypes?

Comment: check if the message from facebook API is empty  `$input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']` if it is dont process the request.

Comment: Interesting ... what would `$input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']` translate to in the C# version? Would it be `turnContext.Activity.Text`?

Comment: I think yes, that would be the relevant entry.

Comment: I think I also need to figure out what `ActivityTypes` the bot framework maps these Facebook Event types too as I think that is the root of the issue.  But then the Dev and Staging bots subscribe to the same events and don't see these issues, but those bots are in the Development state so I'm thinking that may be playing a part too.

Comment: I believe most Facebook events get mapped to either Messages or ConversationUpdates in the BotFramework. Its likely an event in Messenger that gets mapped to ConversationUpdate in the BotFramework like a Handover Event is triggering your welcome message. It would help if you added the code that handles your ConversationUpdate/Welcome Message to your question.

Comment: Ah I meant to update this as I solved it. Will add an answer